# Conteo distintivo en base a dos columnas power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Aquí hay un ejemplo de lo que estoy intentando hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy buscando una medida DAX para obtener un recuento distintivo de los #id que se muestran para cada fecha independientemente de si se encuentran en la columna "id1" o "id2".

El resultado sería así:

ID#1 = 1

ID#2 = 1

ID#3 = 1

ID#4 = 1

ID#5 = 1

Y el recuento distintivo sería igual a 5.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: No lo lograrás así. Debes ir a Power Query y crear una columna que sea la concatenación de las dos. Luego en Power BI creas una medida que sea  `DISTINCTCOUNT(Tabla[ColumnaCreada])`